# "Can not perform this action after onSaveInstanceState" when processing click events

Tags: android, fragment

Yes, I know what does this mean by "can't perform ... onSaveInstanceState", but you see that I committed the `FragmentTransaction` during the process of `onClick`. I suppose at that time the fragments should be at "normal" state. So what can be the cause of this exception?

[image]

Comment: You might be doing some UI operation after the `Fragment` is finished.. or its current state is saved

Comment: all the operations are done in the UI thread.  I just wanna know why the states are still in saved-state.